# netcat chat client over the internet

Tags: netcat

I want to be able to use net cat for a chat client but I can only figure out how to do it over local network. For what I want to do I need to be able to let people connect over the internet.

Say I am in town bloomberg and my friend is in homestuck street, how could I use netcat to let us chat through the terminal.

Comment: If you are both behind a router with a built-in firewall, you will need to configure both firewalls so that they will forward messages on a certain port to your respective machines. In some routers this is called "port forwarding" or "virtual server".

Comment: Above is a pure networking question unrelated to Ubuntu...

Comment: I'm doing this in ubuntu. Sorry though, I didn't know where else to ask. :/